# Grab the value from a span (not the text) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to grab the value of a span attribute but am only successful so far in grabbing the text (which I don't need in this case).

```js
// I want the value to return "10"


myValue = document.querySelector(".count-total").getElementByID("data-multiply")
console.log(myValue)
```

```html
<div class="count-total">
  <span data-multiply="10">20 Doses</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please  post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. - there is no HTML in your snippet

Comment: Try `document.querySelector(".count-total [data-multiply]").dataset.multiply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the `span` with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and then get the `multiply` value from the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```js
const span = document.querySelector('.count-total span');
console.log(span.dataset);
const val = span.dataset.multiply;
console.log(val);
```

```html
<div class="count-total">
  <span data-multiply="10">20 Doses</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dataset` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

```js
const node = document.querySelector(".count-total span[data-multiply]")
console.info(node.dataset.multiply)
```

```html
<div class="count-total">
  <span data-multiply="10">20 Doses</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementByID("data-multiply")` is neither syntactically correct nor will it get the data attribute

it is spelled `getElementById` but is used when an element has an ID

You need to use the querySelector with the complete path and use the [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
// I want the value to return "10"
const myValue = document.querySelector(".count-total span").dataset.multiply;
console.log(myValue)
```

```html
<div class="count-total">
  <span data-multiply="10">20 Doses</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` (note the lower case `d` at the end) looks for an element with a matching `id="xyz"` value. None of your elements has an `id`.

Assuming the `span` with `data-multiply` is the **only** (or at least first) element with that `data-*` attribute, you can find it with `querySelector` using an attribute selector (`[data-multiply]`) and read its attribute value via [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) or [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```js
const element = document.querySelector("[data-multiply]");
const myValue = element.getAttribute("data-multiply");
console.log(myValue);
const myValue2 = element.dataset.multiply;
console.log(myValue2);
```

```html
<div class="count-total">
  <span data-multiply="10">20 Doses</span>
</div>
```